# How can you assign an id to a newly created HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

EDIT:
Using this code in NetBeans:

```
var ele = document.createElement("div");
ele.id = 'tempId1';
ele.innerHTML = "TEST";
document.querySelector("body").append(ele);
document.getElementById("tempId1").innerHTML= "TEST2";
```

Gives me the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating     'document.querySelector("body").append(ele)') (13:47:52:032 | error, javascript)
at global code (public_html/index.html:34:42)
```

before appendingnull (13:47:52:036)

and this code:

```
  var newElement = document.createElement("DIV");
newElement.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");
console.log("before appending" +  document.getElementById("uniqueIdentifier"));
document.body.append(newElement);
console.log("after appending" + document.getElementById("uniqueIdentifier"));
document.getElementById("uniqueIdentifier").innerHTML = "hello";
```

gives me the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'document.body.append(newElement)') (13:47:52:037 | error, javascript)
at global code (public_html/index.html:51:21)
```

The code seems to execute okay in Chrome, but not in NetBeans Embedded Webkit Browser. I'm now wondering if something else is the problem now, but at least I can make it work. Thanks all.

---

ORIGINAL TEXT:
(I am very bad at programming.)

I'm trying to create an new HTML element, assign a new ID to it, and then call that ID and output something by using .innerHTML to put a string into it.

If I use

```
var newElement = document.createElement("DIV");
```

and then either:

```
document.newElement.id = "newId";
```

OR:

```
newElement.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");
```

and then try to assign text and output that using the new element:

```
document.getElementById("uniqueIdentifier").innerHTML = "TEST OUTPUT";
```

then nothing happens.

I've tried many configurations, but I can never output anything using a new id.

I've also copied and pasted code that people said would assign an id to a newly generated object, but I can never output anything using the new id.

Here's an example of something I copied:

```
var ele = document.createElement('div');
var id = 'temp1';
ele.setAttribute('id', id);
```

To this I added an additional line:

```
document.getElementById("temp1").innerHTML = "TEST";
```

which fails to output anything.

Another example of code I tried:

```
var el = document.createElement('div'), 
staticPart = 'myUniqeId',
i = 0; 
el.id = staticPart + i; 
el.getAttribute('id'); 
el.id;
```

To which I again added

```
document.getElementById("myUniqeId0").innerHTML = "OUTPUT TEST";
```

Doesn't work. I've been stuck for a few days now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the part that you are missing here is appending the newly created element to the DOM. You have created new element but haven't placed it at any position on the DOM. you will need to call `<someElement>.append(yourNewElement)` to add your new element to the DOM. Refer to answers below.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly set the inner html of the element using.

```
    ele.id = 'temp1';
    ele.innerHTML = "TEST";
```

and then to see the output on your page you need to append this element into some already existing element of your html. Here it is being appended to html body.

```js
var ele = document.createElement('div');
ele.id = 'temp1';
ele.innerHTML = "TEST";
document.querySelector("body").append(ele);
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating an element.you can set id by using setAttribute and then append it to the body and then try to set its content

If you are not appending it to the body and trying to search the dom as document.getElementById("uniqueIdentifier") would return null ,so that's the reason you are not able to see the content

check this snippet

```js
var newElement = document.createElement("DIV");


newElement.setAttribute("id", "uniqueIdentifier");

console.log("before appending" +  document.getElementById("uniqueIdentifier"));



document.body.append(newElement);

console.log("after appending" + document.getElementById("uniqueIdentifier"));

document.getElementById("uniqueIdentifier").innerHTML = "hello";
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `document.getElementById` function only after that element is part of the document. As long as you didn't append the element you created to one of the elements in your document, you can't `get`it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by just 3 lines of code!!!

```js
$('body').html('<div></div>');
$('div').attr('id', 'test');
$('div#test').html("<h1>Hello World</h1>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```